# Incorrect columns order in append dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to append two data frames in python. First one contains Header row and second one is Data. Header rows contains two rows as

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,....
Int,String,String,....
```

And the data contains multiple rows as data

```
1,John,Mark,....
2,Kedar,Mac,....
```

and so on

I tried using below mentioned code but still no luck. dfcols is header dataframe and Dat1 contains all data in data frame.
Both the data frames are giving proper result when printed separately. But when I append both these data frames then second data frames(which contains data) columns order gets Irregular.(Please note that the data contains some numeric values as well)

```
df1=dfcols.append(Dat1, ignore_index=True,sort=False)
print(df1)
```

I need the output as

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,....
Int,String,String,....
1,John,Mark,....
2,Kedar,Mac,....
```

Comment: Is df1 column count equal to df2 count?

Comment: yes.. Exactly same

Comment: Insert the headers from your df1 to your df2 first then do the concatenation. Placing answer, wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('your_df1_file.csv', header = 0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('your_df2_file.csv', header = None)
column_headers_df1 = df1.columns.tolist()
df2.columns = column_headers_df1
final_df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concat your two df in one.

```py
df1 = pd.concat([dfcols, Dat1.rename(columns=dfcols.columns)], reset_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create MultiIndex for df2 by values from two rows of df1

```
>>> df2.columns= df1.apply(lambda x: x.tolist(), axis=1).values.tolist()
>>> df2
  Col1   Col2   Col3
   Int String String
0    1   John   Mark
1    2  Kedar    Mac
```